# Spock + Gradle. Parallel tests execution

Tags: gradle, fork, integration-testing, spock

I'm using **gradle + spock + groovy** for integration testing. For now my test suite execution time is about 1h. So I've decided to look into parallel tests execution.

Gradle can parallel tests with the help of forks ([maxParallelForks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:maxParallelForks)). But in this case I'm limited with the (number of forks == number of cores on my machine).

Spock itself doesn't have support for parallel tests execution.

So my question: is there any gradle plugin (or test framework) similar to [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) that have both options for parallel test execution (via Threads and Forks)?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the docs says that about `maxParallelForks`

```
The maximum number of forked test processes to execute in parallel. The default value is 1 (no parallel test execution). It cannot exceed the value of max-workers for the current build.
```

However, you can increase max workers above your number of processors, via a [cmdline parameter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html).

```
--max-workers (incubating)

Sets the maximum number of workers that Gradle may use. For example--max-workers=3. The default is the number of processors.
```

So you can execute with more forks than your processors, only in data driven iterations can not be parallelized this way.

Comment: It worked like a charm. For future reference, it works for grails 2.4.